# How to extract event_type from AuthBlockingEvent dataclass firebase cloud function

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-identity

I would like to extract the associated sign-in method used, like Google or email/password from the event.

Given the Google Documentations here for [Getting user and context information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=2nd#getting_user_and_context_information), some fields are not available on the `AuthBlockingEvent` dataclass.

For example I can extract the following:

```py
from firebase_functions import https_fn, identity_fn, options

@identity_fn.before_user_signed_in()
def handle_user(
    event: identity_fn.AuthBlockingEvent,
) -> identity_fn.BeforeSignInResponse | None:
    email = event.data.email
    uid = event.data.uid
    event_id = event.event_id
    event_type = event.credential
```

However, the following does on exist on the even signature.

```py
from firebase_functions import https_fn, identity_fn, options

@identity_fn.before_user_signed_in()
def handle_user(
    event: identity_fn.AuthBlockingEvent,
) -> identity_fn.BeforeSignInResponse | None:
    event_type = event.event_type
    auth_type = event.auth_type
    resource = event.resource
    # etc
```

I also opened an issue on the official repository https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python/issues/180

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the information I wanted through `additional_user_info.provider_id` which can have a value of `google.com`, `password`, etc. depending on how the user is signing in.

On firebase Blocking functions, if you set any of the Additional provider token credentials, you can also access `event.credential.sign_in_method` which can also have a value of `google.com`, `password`, etc.

```py
@identity_fn.before_user_signed_in()
def handle_user(
    event: identity_fn.AuthBlockingEvent,
) -> identity_fn.BeforeSignInResponse | None:
    sign_in_provider = event.additional_user_info.provider_id
    sign_in_method = event.credential.sign_in_method if event.credential else None
```